# Keep jquerymobile header on fullscreen video

Tags: jquery-mobile, video.js

Im working on jquerymobile app, where I have a few videos from youtube. 
To play videos I am using video.js html5 player with youtube plugin.

When video is playing I have some video description showing in the header, which works fine.

The problem Im having is when activating fullscreen mode on the player, video resize fullscreen and header disappears which is not what I want.

I would like to keep header visible even if video is on fullscreen.
I tried to use data-fullscreen attribute, adjust z-index of header but nothing works - header disappears on fullscreen.

Is there any way to keep header always visible on fullscreen?

I created simple demo here http://jsfiddle.net/machumba/ewbpy5s7/2/

```
<iframe 
    width="100%" 
    height="300" 
    src="http://jsfiddle.net/machumba/ewbpy5s7/2/embedded/"
    allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" 
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I just had a look on chrome browser and V js, gets a (z-index: 2147483647;) value so try and give your header a higher value and see if it helps. Try also a fixed position for the header

Comment: Thanks,I think the problem is that z-index.Fixed position of the header is taken care of jquerymobile. Element with data-role='header' and data-position='fixed'is getting automatically the class .ui-header-fixed which has position: fixed;left:0;right:0;width:100%;z-index:1000. Overriding this class z-index to anything higher than 2147483647 defaults (by browser?) to 2147483647

Comment: What class sets this z-index of fullscreen video? If I knew I could override this to some smaller value instead.

Comment: you need to right click on the browser your are using when on full screen and inspect the css elements. On chrome. what sets the z-index for the player is (:-webkit-full-screen)

Comment: Thanks, you were right it's (:-webkit-full-screen) rule, but Im not able to override :webkit-full-screen since is user agent style . If I take video off the page the header is still underneath,dont matter if I set its z-index to 2147483648, seems like fullscreen is defined in webkit the way that nothing else apart from fullscreen video can be seen on the page.

Comment: not sure, but can you add (:-webkit-full-screen: 9999999999) to the header style.

Comment: if I add this to the header nothing happens, even I get css error: Unknown vendor-specific extension -webkit-full-screen :(